# Google Map API v2 marker wrongly displayed on nexus 10

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, nexus-10

As you can see with the two screenshots below (first screenshot on my nexus 5 and second one on my nexus 10 )it seems that I have some troubles with android google map Api V2 to display markers correctly on my nexus 10. It is running the same code but markers are to small and do not respect the anchor parameter ( the marker is supposed to be exactly on the road ). I decided to display the default marker to be sure it has nothing to do with my custom markers.

To create my marker I simply do something like that :

```
MarkerOptions option = new MarkerOptions();
bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker();
option.icon(bitmapDescriptor);
option.anchor(0.5f, 1);
option.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```

[image: nexus 5]

[image: nexus 10]

Comment: The code could be the same, but the values of latitude and longitude might differ. What is the source of these values? GPS?

Comment: Points come from a server thus location is exactly the same.

Comment: Possibly a bug in the library code. Can you post an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2 ?

Comment: Done. It's really weird that I am the only one facing this issue. Maybe I should try with your Android Maps Extensions to see if it happens again.

Comment: Android Maps Extensions is just a wrapper around official Google library and it won't fix it. There were people facing similar issue, but that was for XXHDPI devices (Samsung Galaxy S4, HTC One, etc.). Here it is: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5439. Google Maps Android API v2 still feels like beta.

Comment: I saw this issue but nexus 10 is a xhpi device and this xxhdpi bug seems to be solved.